# can there exists subring of nonzero characteristic if ring has zero characteristic?

Tags: ring-theory, characteristics

**Question** Let $R$ be a ring such that $\operatorname{char}(R)$ is $0$ and $S$ is subring of $R$ then $\operatorname{char}(S)$ is $0$.

**My attempt**: If $\operatorname{char}(R)=0$ then $\nexists n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, $nx=0$ for all $x\in R$. I don't know how to go proceed further. please help...

Note: **ring $R$ may not have unity...**

Comment: Do your rings always have a $1$? Are subrings required to respect the unity? (There are different conventions about that, so you should specify). If no, then $\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ is a rather simple example.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin sir, example of what? Ring with characteristic $0$ and having subring with characteristic $2$ (Am I correct?)

Comment: Yes, **of course** that's what it is an example of. Are you really not seeing it? $\{0\}\times(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ would be a subring of characteristic $2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "ring" you mean "ring with unity", and subrings are therefore required to contain the unity, then it is easy to see that the answer is "no", since in that setting the characteristic is the nonnegative generator of the kernel of the ring map $\mathbb{Z}\to R$ given by sending $1$ to $1_R$.

If you either do not require rings to have a unity, or do not require subrings to have the same unity as their overrings (uncommon when you *do* require a unity), then taking the direct product of a ring of characteristic $0$, $R_0$, and a ring of positive characteristic $R_c$, will give you an example $R_0\times R_c$: because the product has characteristic $0$, but $\{0\}\times R_c$ has characteristic $\mathrm{char}(R_c)\gt 0$.

Comment: Sir, Thank you so much for the answer. Still I am confused in one perticular special case, If I add just one condition that $R$ is commutative then is result holds true? That is, If $R$ is commutative ring (may not have unity)  such that $char(R)=0$ and $S$ subring of $R$ then $char(S)=0$ is true? Please reply...

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi: There is nothing in my example prohibiting the rings from being commutative, so it should be patently clear that the answer is still *of course not*. Take $\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your help. I asked this question, because in book "Contemporary abstract algebra by Gallian" there is an exercise in chapter 16 which says "If $R$ is commutative ring then show that, characteristic of $R[x]$ is same as characteristic of $R$

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Context needs to be given **in the question**, *ahead of time*, not in a comment after everything is said and done.

Answer (score 0):

Subrings are closed under addition and the inclusion of $S$ into $R$ is an injection, so if $n\cdot1=0$ in $S$ then that is also the case in $R$.

Comment: What if $R$ has no unity?

Comment: $How do you assumed that $S$ has unity?